# RequestScoped in Play 2.7

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework, guice

I am trying to inject a UnitOfWork into my repositories using Guice in Play.  I am trying to configure the UnitOfWork to be RequestScoped, but there does not seem to be a way to do this.

I have googled and been on stack overflow for a while now and have not come across a clear answer for this.  What is the state of RequestScoped for Play in 2019?

Answer (score 0):

Play Framework is Stateless by default. From its [Web Page](https://www.playframework.com):

> Play is based on a lightweight, stateless, web-friendly architecture.

So everything that you inject with *Guice* is created newly.

There is an exception if you annotate a `class` with `Singleton` then this class will be injected only once per Node.

Comment: Doing my own testing, this does not seem to be the case.  I get 2 different instances of my UnitOfWork in the same request.  I can fix this by using a `.toInstance()` binding, but then I get the same instance over multiple requests, which is also something I don't want :)

Comment: ok - I corrected my answer - I did not get your case correctly - but could you not easily fix that by constructing, e.g. a `case class` and using that for the request state?